# centos 7 can't run on new pc

Tags: centos, clone

I have a fully working centos 7 pc, I want to change that pc so I need to take out the HDD from old to new PC( keep all files and VM config) but my new PC cant find the centos 7 EFI file to boot from.

Comment: In other words, I have a HP laptop running centos 7 I want to move it to my new PC(desktop)

Comment: what is your question?